# Using column values for function argument...can I do this in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, function

So I'm using PostgreSQL right now and I currently have a table that is created with the following function:

```
CREATE TABLE summaryTable AS (
    SELECT d.name, d.store_id, d.rental_id
    FROM detailedTable AS d
    GROUP BY d.store_id, d.name
    ORDER BY d.name ASC
)
```

I also have written a function that takes a genre of movie as its argument and returns the number of times it is found in the DB. I want to use the results of this function and add them to a new column in the table shown above. But the argument would come from *d.name* in the table above. When SELECT * FROM summaryTable is run we see a table like the following (keep in mind, this is only a section of the table) https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsCsA.png
I wanted to write a function that would use the first row, first column value as its argument, and count up how many times that genre was found on the summaryTable and return a table that included the genre name and how many times it appeared in store one and how many times it appeared in store two.

The function below was what I came up with but it does not fulfill what I am trying to do, just thought it might help with understanding...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countGenre (genre varchar)
RETURNS integer AS $totals$
DECLARE totals integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(d.name) INTO totals
    FROM detailedTable AS d
    WHERE d.name = genre AND d.store_id = 1
    GROUP BY d.name;
    RETURN totals;
    END; $totals$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So the end result would look something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpbzm.png

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your language is vague. "the column", "a column" to "that column", and so on. I lost in translation of one sentence, as it were long and named too much subjects with the same name, namely.

Comment: Can you post a code?

Comment: Your description is very unclear and also incorrect. What you have shown is not a function, but a query and the outcome of this query is no table (it selects data from a table), but a result set. Please show some sample input and the expected outcome you want to build. And please point out if you want to do a query (this means only select and show data) or to change data.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. I'm having a hard time explaining what I mean.

Comment: Ok. Could you please edit your question and add sample input data and the expected result?

Comment: "add them to a new column" or you need to add the result into a specific column?
Is this a onetime job? if this is not a one time job, do you need to grow your columns dynamically? please give some clear idea about your real requirement with a sample.

Comment: In a real world scenario, it would not be a one time job, but for this yes its only needed one time. I need to create a new column to add the results

Answer (score 0):

Structure of data is unclear for me (please provide next time full table definition), but you don't need to have a function to do a count, just subquery.

First, you must clearly define what you want to count, because function count now all occurences of `name` in `store_id = 1`. In comments you mentioned, that it should count diferent `retail_id` regardless of store (or maybe inside each store ?).

if summaryTable already axists and have additional field added then it can be updated by subselect or by function

```sql
update summaryTable
set aggregated_count = (
     select count(distinct retail_id) 
       from detailedTable 
       where detailedTable.name = summaryTable.name)
```

```sql
update summaryTable
set aggregated_count =    countGenre(name)
```

Comment: I have summaryTable already created with columns named *name*, *store_id*, and *rental_id*. I need to write a function that counts the number of *rental_id's* with the same *name* value and add the count to a new column in summaryTable. It looks like what you suggested would only create a new table and uses countGenre as if it were already written. I need to use the values that are already in the *name* column as the argument for the function so it knows which *name* to count, but I think I can only do it explicitly, ``` countGenre('Action') ```  rather than have it be done automatically.

Comment: You must better describe structure. You have store_id and retail_id... when one name is in multiple stores and only one retail_id is assigned to all of them count is 1 ?

Comment: I see the confusion here. The column isn't retail, its *rental_id*. The rental_id describes a transaction taking place, like a purchase, so these are all unique. Name describes the genre and  can appear multiple times in the table and store_id is one of two values (1 or 2)